# How to add new data to the already existing group for a visualization in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, grouping, powerbi-desktop

I am adding contract ID(containing 4 digits numbers like 1234,2345,2323 etc. ) in a Group in Power BI and WO in a different group. Whenever a new contract ID is added to the live data how can I add that contract ID automatically to that Contract ID group for that visualization so that it wont create separate bars for each contract ID?
[image]

This is how it should look like. but whenever the data is updates in the live excel sheet it looks like this .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Grouping will remain a manual process, if you approach it like that.
You can semi automate it: If only ONE type of values will be added, you can select the option at the bottom right and rename the Group to that cateogry. THis will automatically bin ALL unbinned values under this category. This dangerous however, once a second category value arrives that shouldn't be counted there.

[image: Option at the bottom right]

**A better way** to approach this problem would be to instead of using groups, using a calculated column.
This requires you to have very clear rules on how to categorize your data. If your rule mentioned above (4 digit numbers are ALWAYS contract ids) is robust, then you can use that. But you can also add further rules to refine it, etc.

To add a calulated column, select your view tab, select tabletools in the toolbar and then hit 'new Column'. Then you can add your code for how this new column is supposed to be calucalted in DAX. [Link to MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns)

[image: adding a calculated column]

The DAX would look something like this.

```
calculated_col= 
if(
    len(Table[ColumnName]) = 4, // evaluate length of content of the Column
    "ContractID",
    "Workorder"
)
```